# Why does max() in this case return 7?

Tags: python, lambda, max

```
l = [7, 9, 5, 6, 13, 5, 15, 3]
t = max(l, key=lambda g:g if g%9==1 else 0)
```

`t` is the maximum element of `l`, whose remainder of the division by 9 is 1.

In this case, `t` equals 7. But this list doesn't have any elements whose remainder of the division by 9 is 1 at all! Why doesn't `t` equal 0?

Comment: There are no 0s in `l`, so why are you expecting a 0 in the output? Maybe you're confusing `max(l, key=<func>)` with `max(map(<func>, l))`?

Comment: BTW, check out [ask] for tips on how to write a good title. This title is not terrible, but it doesn't give any context. Instead you might put something like "Why does max() return the first element when the key function is the same for every element?" though that might imply more knowledge about the problem, so it depends where you're coming from.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lambda calculates the key for each value to be `0`, and so with all elements having an equivalent key, the first element is returned.

The lambda is simply used to calculate the value for comparison, it does not convert the value that is returned.

Comment: Convert on the output? Or, if what you want is "the maximum element of `l` whose remainder by 9 is 1", use `filter` or a list comprehension to first select those elements, then get the maximum.

Answer (score 0):

> this list doesn't have any elements whose remainder of the division by 9 is 1 at all

`max()` will throw an error on an empty sequence, by the way; it would not return 0. If you wanted to filter the elements **then** get the max, you'd write that this way

```
t = 0
try:
    t = max(filter(lambda g: g % 9 == 1, l))
except ValueError:
    print('No values in the list have a remainder of 1, when divided by 9')
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at the keys actually being compared to one another:

```
>>> [x if x % 9 == 1 else 0 for x in [7, 9, 5, 6, 13, 5, 15, 3]]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

According to the key, no later value is *larger* than 7 (even though they are all *as large* as 7), so 7 is the result.

If *any* (positive) value in the list were congruent to 1 modulo 9, then `max` would return the first such value instead of 7.

```
>>> l = [7, 9, 5, 6, 13, 5, 15, 3, 10]
>>> max(l, key=lambda g:g if g%9==1 else 0)
10
```

It just so happens that the key can only return a non-negative value that equal to 0 or greater than 9. (`-8 % 9 == 1`, but then the key is `-8 < 7`.)